# Design API endpoint for resource that needs to return different forms of data for different pages

Tags: api, rest, prisma, api-design

I'm using prisma to communicate with db, with nested relations and all.

I have a resource that is requested by multiple pages. Each page needs different set of data from the resource so each page sends different query params. Simplified exmaple would be: one page needs price and name, the other page needs price, name and collection.

Example query would be

```js
prisma.product.findMany({
  where: {
    ...(collectionName ? { collection: {
      is: {
        collectionName,
      },
    } } : {}),
    ...(productName ? { productName } : {}),
  },
  ...(select ? { // checking if its array and mapping it is omitted for the example
    select: {
      [select]: true, // no way to select fields from relation
  } } : {}),
});
```

But the query becomes more complex as I add new pages that use the resource, adding more and more filters and/or `select`s, and pages end up requesting-receiving unnecessary data if not using `select`s.

It feels rather complex and like there's a way to make it better, like splitting endpoints into multiple or sending the whole `Prisma.ProductFindManyArgs` from the frontend.

How can I reduce complexity and increase reusability?

**upd**. Is it a good idea to send the whole thing from front-end, like it's done in GraphQL? I mean, in GraphQL you send exactly what fields you want and additional data, like page and amount of documents per page (for pagination). So I was thinking if it would be OK to just send the whole object, containing all the information that is required to provide the data I need (`where`, `select`, `include`, `take`, `skip`, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a GraphQL API, which allows for more fine-grained queries by allowing the client to specify exactly what fields it wants to receive. Using a GraphQL API would also allow for more flexibility and customization and may also simplify the backend code by reducing the number of endpoints.

Comment: I already considered graphql but I don't have time to convert from rest to graphql.

Answer (score 0):

I would always start with REST principles, rather than technology. Sounds like you have clients who want slightly different resources, but that does not mean you need to go down to a field by field level.

I would model `products` and `collections` separately, via distinct URLs. Each operation can use its own query parameters. Although there are multiple entry points, you can share logic within the API.

```
GET /products
GET /product/44
GET /product/44/details
GET /collections
GET /collections/6
GET /collections/6/products
```

Each endpoint can return a different payload. By default a product could return the most commonly used fields, eg name and price. Note the separate `details` object, for clients who want more rarely used product info. This small step can be surprisingly useful in splitting up large objects.

The main result should be an API whose endpoints make most sense for clients, and gives them the best choices. It should also enable you to keep your code maintainable as it grows.

Allowing a client to select fields to return is not usually a requirement, and can add unnecessary complexity to an API. Instead aim for a solid resource design of medium sized objects. If a client receives an object with 6 fields and only uses 2 of them it is usually fine.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the comment. Isn't /product/44/details redundant? What's the point of GET /product/44 in this case?
I decided to supply a "requestType" param in requests. Depending on the param different handlers would be called with different data returned to the client.

Answer (score 0):

design an API endpoint for a resource that needs to return different forms of data for different pages:

Endpoint URL: /resource

HTTP Method: GET

Request Parameters:

page (required): The name or ID of the page that the user is requesting the data for.
Response:
The API endpoint returns a JSON object with the data for the requested page. The structure of the JSON object will depend on the page that is requested.

Example JSON response for page "homepage":

```
{
"featured_items": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Product A",
        "price": 19.99
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Product B",
        "price": 29.99
    }
],
"banner_image": "https://example.com/banner.jpg",
"promotions": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Get 10% off your first purchase",
        "code": "WELCOME10"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Free shipping on orders over $50",
        "code": null
    }
]
```

}

Example JSON response for page "product"

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Product A",
"description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod mauris at tellus pulvinar, non laoreet felis maximus. Nulla vel ipsum nisi. Vestibulum auctor tincidunt orci at convallis. Suspendisse rutrum odio libero, sit amet malesuada lectus tincidunt vel. Sed mattis semper luctus. Curabitur nec gravida est.",
"price": 19.99,
"reviews": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "rating": 4,
        "comment": "Great product!"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "rating": 2,
        "comment": "Not as good as I expected"
    }
]
```

}

Notes:

1.The page parameter is required to ensure that the API endpoint returns the correct data for the requested page.
2.The structure of the JSON response will vary based on the requirements of each page.
3.Depending on the nature of the data and the requirements of the pages, the response format could also be XML, HTML, or some other format.